# Assign array of two elements to two variables

Tags: c++, c++17

How can I assign array of two elements to two variables?

Here is example of my idea (no valid code):

```
getTwoValues() {
    int a = 7;
    int b = 5;
    return {a, b};
}

int x, y = getTwoValues();

// Expected output: x = 7, y = 5
```

Comment: The top answer on the post has what you really want: [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

Comment: TLDR; `getTwoValues() {` => `auto getTwoValues() {` and `int x, y = getTwoValues();` => `auto [x, y] = getTwoValues();`